# .[Android] + [SQLite] = [Android-SQLite]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

We have [21k+ questions about SQLite on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+sqlite). Most people seem to tag their questions with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite), but not [android-sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sqlite), and most [android-sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sqlite) questions also have the other tag(s).

The Android version of SQLite might differ a bit from other versions, but do we really need the [android-sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sqlite) tag?

Comment: Probably depends on how different the implementations are.  If the question (and any answers) is applicable to SQL Lite in general and not specific only to the android implementation, then seems unnecessary for the android-sqlite tag.  But if the answers would only work on the android implementation, then the tag provides some value.

Comment: I cannot find anything that claims android-sqlite differs from sqlite. Maybe there isn't a difference after all?

Comment: Did Google do some code customizations in their build of android-sqlite? If so, they could affect the use of it, so maybe keep the tag.

Comment: Maybe use android+sqlite for general questions about sqlite that happens to be used on android, whereas reserve android-sqlite for any oddities that seem specific to the android version of sqlite...

Comment: How about mass editing the questions and converting them to `android-sqlite` (only those questions which are specific to Android version of sqlite)? Is it recommended?

Answer (score 13):

The code in the `android.database.sqlite` package is not a complete wrapper of the SQLite C API: many functions are missing, and in most contexts, SQL parameters can only be strings.

Furthermore, it has several additions on top of the C API, such as the `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `SQLiteQueryBuilder` classes, the implementation of nested transactions, and the `LOCALIZED` and `UNICODE` collations.

So [android-sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sqlite) can be useful.
(Well, it could be if it were used consistently …)